# jquery hover not working properly in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So my idea is to have title underlined and on hover it should disappear, but for some reason, I can't find a way to do it properly.

Here is my code:

```
a.attr("href", jQuery('.underlined').attr("href"));    
a.hover(
  function() {
    jQuery(this).css({"text-decoration":"none"});
  },
  function() {
    jQuery(this).css({"text-decoration":"underline"});
  }
);
```

Currently this is working like this: when a user loads the page the title is not underlined, and when user hovers over the title and move cursor away then that title is underlined and from then on it is working as it should.

Just to recap what I want:

1. Title should be underlined by default
2. When a user hovers over the title, underline should disappear

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do u use jQuery when this can be achieved through Css??

Comment: no I can't use pure CSS, I am using jQuery because of the other parts of the code which are added depends what is selected. So I just wanted to extend it with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a css rule based on a class (in style.css) , eg .newclass{text-decoration:underline;}. Then uses jQuery to [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/). , or removeClass to make the changes.

Add another class called something like 'alreadyunderlined' the the title, then before removing the 'newclass' simply check if the 'alreadyunderlined' class exists. That way you can be sure it only get's changed the first time you hover over the title.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Most straight forward answer if you have to use JavaScript to do it.

Comment: Yeap it does. Thank you.

Comment: Great stuff Morpheus, glad you got it working. That being the case please mark the answer as correct, otherwise the question remains unanswered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `text-decoration: underline;` be default value, when page loads. By using CSS:

```
.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

or by using jQuery (javascript (but why?)) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.underline').css({'text-decoration' : 'underline'});
});
```

Comment: As I said earlier based on selection, there is jquery code that runs and it is easier to do it with jquery...